# Why DispatchQueue.main.async do impact on the cell autoresizing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I am working on the autoresizing cells that are presented in the `UITableView`.

They are performing well except when I try to set image to `UIImageView` from `DispatchQueue`. When I set image directly all working fine.

Example:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self._thumbnailImageView.image = image
}
```

Could you share what I am missing and why `DispatchQueue.main.async` block could impact on cell resizing.

Comment: If you are already in the Main thread, you do not have to do an `DispatchQueue.main.async` to set the image. This can reduce the performance because the setting of image will be delayed. Imagine that current UI update must be finished before the iOS app use again the Main thread to set the new image and redraw it.

Comment: @Hoa thx for the suggestions but I am using DispatchQueue.main.async to set image from background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your call-stack already let the table view know it needed layout updating, but the async one did not.

Add a

```
tableView.setNeedsLayout()
```

inside the async block to see if that works.  You might only need to do it on the cell.

Comment: Is it ok if I will call this from tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ? Or it should be called directly in code block?

Comment: It needs to be in that code block so that it happens after you update the image.

Comment: Thx for the help but this step does not help me.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that in this case is more suitable to use:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async
```

Because of the Quality of Service Class. In my case I should use `.userInteractive`.

> Work that is interacting with the user, such as operating on the main
>   thread, refreshing the user interface, or performing animations. If
>   the work doesn’t happen quickly, the user interface may appear frozen.
>   Focuses on responsiveness and performance.

But really I need more explanation why `DispatchQueue.main.async` is not performing well.